# HtttpURLConnection never uses gzip

Tags: java, android, http

I'm currently developing an app, that should measure (fairly precisely) the size of webpages.

The thing I'm struggling with now is that I need to know the sizes of particular files that are on the website. I have an array of URLs and I try to fetch their headers to get Content-Length, however some files return -1 since they are chunked. If they return -1 I try to download them to get their size.

And here lies the problem - I found out that I always get uncompressed version of the file.

Example file - 
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

When I open it in Chrome, the headers says this:

[image]

However, when I download it using HttpURLConnection, it has a size of 25421 bytes, and when I check the Content-Encoding header, its always null.

```java
connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
connection.connect();
int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

if (contentLength == -1 && connection != null) {
  InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int count = 0, len;
  while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    count += len;
  }
  contentLength = count;
}
```

So the problem is, that I download a webpage with my application, and it says it has (let's say) 400kB. But when I download it using some kind of tool, like http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ , the size is much smaller, like 100kB, since most of the scripts are gzipped, that means the transfer is lower.
I know 300kB is not that much, but when you are using a mobile transfer, every kB counts, and I want my app to be precise.

Could you point me where I make mistake, or how could I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: typically gzip support is compiled into the webserver

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that? I know it is part of the web server, but as I say - when I download the file throught HttpURLConnection it is uncompressed, and when I get it through Chrome on PC it is compressed. I need to get the compressed version....

Comment: By default, this implementation of HttpURLConnection requests that servers use gzip compression. Since getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how many bytes can be read from getInputStream().
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Your HttpURLConnection setup code looks correct to me. You could try setting the User-Agent to a standard browser one, perhaps the server is trying to be more intelligent than it ought to be. Failing that, run your traffic through a debugging proxy like Fiddler or Burp to see what's going on at the network level.

Comment: @Barend could you please copy this to an answer? :) Id like to accept it, as it worked :))

I added

`WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
userAgent = wv.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);`



And it did work! Thanks a lot man, you solved one of my biggest issues so far!

edit: argh... why you cant use newlines in comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HttpURLConnection setup code looks correct to me. You could try setting the User-Agent to a standard browser one, perhaps the server is trying to be more intelligent than it ought to be. Failing that, run your traffic through a debugging proxy like Fiddler or Burp to see what's going on at the network level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iJetty, you have to enable gzip compression first

You have to enable the GzipFilter to make Jetty return compressed content. Have a look here on how to do that: http://blog.max.berger.name/2010/01/jetty-7-gzip-filter.html

You can also use the gzip init parameter to make Jetty search for compressed content. That means if the file file.txt is requested, Jetty will watch for a file named file.txt.gz and returns that.

Comment: Im not sure what are you talking about, I'm using normal HTTPUrlConnection from Android/Java...